# 16bit grayscale raster displays all black in Geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver

I have a 16-bit raster (MrSID) that I want to display in Geoserver 2.0.2 but it is displaying as all black.  If I create a new style similar to the default raster.sld but with graychannel element the image displays correctly.  My question:  Is there a way to modify the default raster.sld so that it handles BOTH RGB and grayscale images (8 and 16-bit)?
Thanks

Comment: The geoserver raster experts hang out on geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net. You will get a better response to this question there.

Comment: are you using WMS or WCS to access the raster through GeoServer